# Golang solution to CTCI 1.2: Check whether two strings are permutations of each other

Tags: algorithm, strings, interview-questions, go

Just started learning Go recently. Did some questions from Cracking the Coding Interview book. Wrote the solutions in Go. Let me know what you think.

https://github.com/samjingwen/ctci

Below is question 1.2 from the book:

```
// CheckPermutation Given two strings, write a method to
// decide if one is a permutation of the other.
func CheckPermutation(s1, s2 string) bool {
    if len(s1) != len(s2) {
        return false
    }
    s1CharCountMap := getCharCountMap(s1)
    s2CharCountMap := getCharCountMap(s2)

    for k, s1Count := range s1CharCountMap {
        s2Count, exists := s2CharCountMap[k]
        if s1Count > s2Count {
            return false
        } else if !exists {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func getCharCountMap(str string) map[rune]int {
    charCount := make(map[rune]int)
    for _, char := range str {
        _, exists := charCount[char]
        if exists {
            charCount[char] += 1
        } else {
            charCount[char] = 1
        }
    }
    return charCount
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code should be correct, maintainable, robust, reasonably efficient, and, most important, readable.

---

Sam wrote:

```
func getCharCountMapSam(str string) map[rune]int {
    charCount := make(map[rune]int)
    for _, char := range str {
        _, exists := charCount[char]
        if exists {
            charCount[char] += 1
        } else {
            charCount[char] = 1
        }
    }
    return charCount
}
```

Peter wrote:

```
func getCharCountMapPeter(str string) map[rune]int {
    charCount := make(map[rune]int)
    for _, char := range str {
        charCount[char]++
    }
    return charCount
}
```

Benchmarks:

```
BenchmarkMapSam-8     463837   2495 ns/op   830 B/op   5 allocs/op
BenchmarkMapPeter-8   539000   1937 ns/op   830 B/op   5 allocs/op
```

Whom would you hire?

---

Sam wrote:

```
func CheckPermutationSam(s1, s2 string) bool {
    if len(s1) != len(s2) {
        return false
    }
    s1CharCountMap := getCharCountMapSam(s1)
    s2CharCountMap := getCharCountMapSam(s2)
    for k, s1Count := range s1CharCountMap {
        s2Count, exists := s2CharCountMap[k]
        if s1Count > s2Count {
            return false
        } else if !exists {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Peter wrote:

```
func CheckPermutationPeter(s1, s2 string) bool {
    if len(s1) != len(s2) {
        return false
    }
    s1CharCountMap := getCharCountMapPeter(s1)
    s2CharCountMap := getCharCountMapPeter(s2)
    if len(s1CharCountMap) != len(s2CharCountMap) {
        return false
    }
    for s1Char, s1Count := range s1CharCountMap {
        if s1Count != s2CharCountMap[s1Char] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Whom would you hire?

---

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec)
>
> [Index expressions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Index_expressions)
>
> if the map is nil or does not contain such an entry, a[x] is the zero
> value for the element type of M
>
> [The zero value](https://go.dev/ref/spec#The_zero_value)
>
> Each element of such a variable or value is set to the zero value for
> its for its type: 0 for numeric types
>
> [IncDec statements](https://go.dev/ref/spec#IncDec_statements)
>
> The "++" and "--" statements increment or decrement their operands by
> the untyped constant 1. As with an assignment, the operand must be
> addressable or a map index expression.
>
> ```
> IncDecStmt = Expression ( "++" | "--" ) .
> ```
>
> The following assignment statements are semantically equivalent:
>
> ```
> IncDec statement    Assignment
> x++                 x += 1
> x--                 x -= 1
> ```

---